# FIFO overflow with DMP on MPU6050 and OLED

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I am using the DMP example code to get yaw pitch roll values, mainly I am interested in pitch value for building a self balancing robot. I am trying to display the pitch values on an OLED screen but I am getting FIFO overflow error which is resulting in delayed sampling and sometimes erratic values.

I tried adding a mpu.resetFIFO() after updating the OLED, but its causing a very slow sampling of the sensor.

I am keen on changing the Arduino Uno for a Teensy board(prolly teensy LC). My main concerns are will changing the processor help? Teensy LC runs @48Mhz compared to Arduino Uno which runs @16Mhz.

Also I went through this link which I found as a probable solution but wasn't able to do it
https://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/27-fifo-overflow/#comment-99

would be great if someone could guide me as to how do I do this?

Comment: I wasnt able to change the bit as instructed, but after some more reading I was able to, I think the OLED updating is causing a delay, which in turn is causing FIFO overrflow(as it might be slow). For now I am not adding  an OLED.
I tested my code on the bot seems like when the bot freaks out after couple of seconds trying to balance itself the values from MPU are erratic and the program freezes, have tried adding decoupling caps on my motors but it doesnt solve the issue. Really confused as to what is happening

Comment: if you can, please post your code ... or post a minimal code that still exhibits the problem ... maybe it can be optimized ... my thinking is to
 handle MPU-6050 comm fully at every iteration of loop() and handle OLED comm in chunks